# I have an app script code that does well in copying numbers I need to copy letters as well is this possible?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a an appscript code that works well copying numbers but I need it to copy expressions like 1xy , 2xy and so forth I can't work out what I need to change in my script - please help

```js
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('myTools')
    .addItem('CopyCells1', 'CopyCells1')
  .addToUi();
}
function CopyCells1(col) {
  var col=col || 1;
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var rg1=sh.getRange("H2:H300");
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var rg2=rg1.offset(0, col);//With this version you can just change this to get into the other columns.
  var vB=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if((vA[i][0]>1)||(vA[i][0]>1)){
      vB[i][0]=vA[i][0];
    }
  }
  rg2.setValues(vB);
}
```

Comment: Google sheets values can be read and written regardless of the type, you shouldn't have any issue. Have you encountered any specific problems or errors?

Comment: yes it copies numbers from 1 above  over to the next column but not words such as xy

Comment: this should be `if((vA[i][0]>1)||(vA[i][0]>1)){` just this `if(vA[i][0]>1){`

Comment: here is a link with it working copies from column H to column I https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F-BtJuwR9pqrOViHe8goU_WWHch564iwAMrX7D3StqY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried  if(vA[i][0]>1){  Thanks Cooper still doesn't copy letters

Comment: Are you trying to copy while filtering empty cells or is this just my impression? If so, the answer is actually way simpler than the ones given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function CopyCells1(col) {
  var col=col || 1;
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var rg1=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1);
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var rg2=rg1.offset(0, col);//With this version you can just change this to get into the other columns.
  var vB=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(vA[i][0]>1||vA[i][0].toString().match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)){
      vB[i][0]=vA[i][0];
    }
  }
  rg2.setValues(vB);
}
```

Comment: make sure you add more coverage to the regex so you are also covering symbols like  "@" if necessary, and number like in the questions examples ("1xy")

Answer (score 2):

The values are not being copied because of your condition:

```js
if((vA[i][0]>1)||(vA[i][0]>1)){
    vB[i][0]=vA[i][0];
}
```

This means that when the vlaue in the first column is a string you will be comparing a string (`1xy`) and a number (1). Javascript is notorious for its weird operator behavior and the expression `"1xy" > 1` evaluates to false so the values in the 2 ranges are never set.

If you want string values to be moved to the next column you will need to adjust you conditional to handle the string values you expect to see. Something like this will do the same as your original but will copy any and all strings to the next column:

```js
if(vA[i][0] > 1 || (typeof vA[i][0] == "string")){
    vB[i][0] = vA[i][0];
}
```

Comment: great thanks Josh that works Much appreciated

Comment: I just tried it and its copying but now its copying empty cells and deleting data is there any way to prevent it copying empty cells ?

Comment: I tried Coopers version and it does  not delete the existing text thanks very much for your help

Comment: @MarkZangel thats becuase empty cells are evaluated as an empty string, you can either check if the string s empty you can simply add it to the end of the evaluation to test its "truthiness": `vA[i][0] > 1 || (typeof vA[i][0] == "string") && vA[i][0]`